# Raster format can be recognized by time slider in ArcGIS Online

Tags: raster, arcgis-online, format, timeslider, story-map

I'm trying to build a time slider on ArcGIS Online with raster datasets. I learned that I need to convert raster to tile package to upload to ArcGIS Online. However, after I upload it, the files cannot be used by the time slider app.

What format of raster data can be recognized by the time slider or is there an alternative way to do a time slider and publish on ArcGIS Online StoryMaps?

Answer (score 0):

First create the time-enabled mosaic dataset: [Time in a mosaic dataset](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/raster-and-images/time-in-a-mosaic-dataset.htm), then [publish that mosaic dataset to ArcGIS Online](https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/linux/share-imagery-as-an-arcgis-online-tiled-map-service.htm).